# Nested repeater with controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I need to create a user interface that resembles the following:

```
cat 1                              Add Category                   Add Point
     cat 1a                        Add Category                   Add Point
          point
     cat 1b                        Add Category                   Add Point
          point
          point
     cat 1c                        Add Category                   Add Point
          cat 1c1                  Add Category                   Add Point
          cat 1c2                  Add Category                   Add Point
               point
```

I was thinking about using a repeater with nested repeaters but I am confused on how to go about this. Also within the repeater when the "Add category" or "Add Point" are clicked I need to show an data entry field with a button within the repeater if possible. is a repeater even a good control to use?

Comment: Since you can have infinite number of nesting I don't think the repeater is a good control for this. For this sort of thing, I would use pure HTML controls coupled with JQuery and Ajax. That way you can construct your markup dynamically on the client side.

Comment: How many levels of nesting can there be? Is it a defined number, or can there be any number of levels?

Comment: there is not a set level of nesting, it is whatever the user wants

Comment: I think a custom user control would be ideal here. The user control would nest children items of itself or a set of 'points'. Also, it would support an 'Add Category' or 'Add point' button.

You could keep values such as degree of nesting in the *ControlState* and can use it to pad the left-most label with respect to the containing control.

Comment: @arviman, so instead of using a repeater control, you are suggesting to create a user control, with a label and two buttons, and simply continuously adding that control if needed.

Comment: A label(for the category), two buttons, *n* number of labels for the points, and *m* number of children (of type of same usercontrol) for each subcategory.

Comment: so for the children I would create a placeholder then correct and in the code behind set all the properties to a new user control and add it to the placeholder?

Comment: @arviman, when I try to set the label text to a value in the user control it is returning a null reference to the label.

Comment: Nevermind I was using catctl = new catctl instead of Page.LoadControl()

Comment: I would like to check your answer as the solution, but I cant cause you didnt respond with an answer.

Comment: Ok i'll add it as an answer so you can close the question.

Comment: @mattgcon let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2872/discussion-between-arviman-and-mattgcon)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Copied from the comments in the question:*
I think a custom user control would be ideal here. The user control would nest children items of itself or a set of 'points'. Also, it would support an 'Add Category' or 'Add point' button. You could keep values such as degree of nesting in the ControlState and can use it to pad the left-most label with respect to the containing control.

You can check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86.aspx) to see how to add a user control. You will optionally also have to do some additional work to maintain the depth of the control using the Control State.

Comment: I have a question in extension this answer, is it possible to loop through the repeater items and get the data item after everything as loaded when a button is clicked?

Comment: No, your data isn't supposed to be preserved during postback. So your DataItem of your Repeater's Items will be null. Only the properties of your controls will be preserved.